# I dont see all azure resources on my azure portal

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-disk

I have a linux VM in my azure account, I am using disk -l command to list all my drives on my VM as fooolow:

```
[root@thermo-breast-cancer-devvm Python-3.7.8]# fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 64 GiB, 68719476736 bytes, 134217728 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 4504F03A-B9F1-4B8B-88BD-4EDC60947270

Device       Start       End   Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1  1026048   2050047   1024000  500M Linux filesystem
/dev/sda2  2050048 134215679 132165632   63G Linux LVM
/dev/sda14    2048     10239      8192    4M BIOS boot
/dev/sda15   10240   1024000   1013761  495M EFI System

Partition table entries are not in disk order.


Disk /dev/sdb: 16 GiB, 17179869184 bytes, 33554432 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x6d61cffb

Device     Boot Start      End  Sectors Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1         128 33552383 33552256  16G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT


Disk /dev/mapper/rootvg-tmplv: 2 GiB, 2147483648 bytes, 4194304 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/rootvg-usrlv: 10 GiB, 10737418240 bytes, 20971520 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/rootvg-homelv: 1 GiB, 1073741824 bytes, 2097152 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/rootvg-varlv: 8 GiB, 8589934592 bytes, 16777216 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/rootvg-rootlv: 2 GiB, 2147483648 bytes, 4194304 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
```

Actually, in addition to sea which is 64 it showing me several additional drives which I can not see on my azure protal when I list all my resources on portal, it shows me just one disk which its size is 64gig, but why the protal doesn't list all other disk as listed by fdik command?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First of all this is the wrong pane to check disks attached to a VM. You can have other disks under the resource group as well. You should be checking it under disks section of a virtual machine.

Now coming back to the point. Azure virtual machine has a temporary disk, sda1 is your temp disk which isn't visible on portal. You are using LVM which is why you have multiple disks in that output even though you have only one physical volume.

Sda14 is the reserved OS partition which is hidden by default (even in windows). And sda13 is your boot partition created out of the same disk with the help of LVM. Below article talks about LVM in detail:

https://opensource.com/business/16/9/linux-users-guide-lvm

Hope this helps.

Comment: Actually, it is showg all volumes for sda which is 64GIG but not for sdb and other disks.